# Which framework to use for media

Tags: java, video, frameworks, multimedia

I have a project wherein video has to be recorded and played back with certain features, like play , pause, reset and has to be synchronised with some other process.

Now the other process is already developed in Java and I have to embed the video into it. So when I started exploring the options, I came across JMF and FMJ. I started analysing pros and cons and what I am concerned FMJ project is dead for 3-4 years. JMF I am finding difficult to get tutorials.

Which of the 2 frameworks should i choose ?

Comment: JMF has been dead longer than FMJ.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I checked their website but nowhere do Java people mention that the project is dead.

Comment: No, they don't.  The lack of information from anybody that claims to have control over JMF, is frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

You can borrow frameworks from jitsi.org, they have extended JMF. See source code for details. There are a lot of good tutorials on JMF you can use that for jitsi.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

QuickTime for Java is also dead, but seems nailed securely enough to its perch to still be useful in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd start at [JavaFx](http://javafx.com/roadmap/#media) - 2.0 is out in beta and looks the best bet going forward.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is after 1 year, but for anyone seeking help, this would be useful.

The following libraries are up and running at the moment

**Xuggler** - Video editing lib. Have artciles as well as video tutorials

**JavaCV** - Wrapper for OpenCV. Can do 1000% more than what the OP has asked for. But still lack of documentation and help.